Invalid HTTP_HOST header for Django app that is running in Cloud Run
I have a Django app running in Cloud Run. Cloud Run is configured as a backend service for External Application Load Balancer.
The service works with different custom domains. The list of domains is changing continuously, so the domain management was moved to the Cloud Armor security policy level to avoid re-deploying the service after updating the domain list. On the Django level, all hosts are allowed: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
example.net is allowed by Cloud Armor security policy and every request to that host is handling by Django app in the Cloud Run.
I started receiving requests from some scanning bots and some of this requests cause an error on the Django app level: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mydomain.com%7d'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
Here are other values from the traceback for this error:
Report at //example。com
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.net%7d'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://example.net%7d//example%E3%80%82com
Django Version: 3.2.25
...

META:
...
HTTP_ACCEPT = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = 'no-cache'
HTTP_FORWARDED = 'for="replaced.ip.address";proto=https'
HTTP_HOST = 'example.net%7d'
PATH_INFO = '//example。com'
QUERY_STRING = ''
RAW_URI = '//example%E3%80%82com'
...

At the same time, logs at the load balancer level don't show these values and it seems like the host value is changing before getting to Cloud Run:
Load balancer log:
httpRequest: {
    ...
    requestMethod: "GET"
    requestUrl: "https://example.net/"
    status: 400
    ...
}

Cloud run log:
httpRequest: {
    requestMethod: "GET"
    requestUrl: "https://example.net%7d//example%E3%80%82com"
    status: 400
}

The main question is: How can this behavior be reproduced? How is it possible to change HOST and PATH values on a flight after a request passes the load balancer? Or is it something related to Django, and these values are added during request processing?
I tried sending requests with invalid host value to reproduce the error, but these requests were rejected by Load Balancer and never reached the Cloud Run application.

so it looks more like an encoding issue in your URL.  Modify your Django middleware to clean and validate the HTTP_HOST header before it’s processed further
'example.net%7d' your url should be sanitized such that it handles your url properly. '%7d' looks like the issue

%7d is definitely the issue. But there is no way to make a requests that will contain this symbol "}" or its ASCII representation as "%7d". Requests to example.net} or example.net%7d return an error on a socket level - nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

At the same time, adding this symbol to the Host header leads to rejecting the request on the load balancer level without reaching the Django app: Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request
